# Clicking welcome notification on international Stack Overflow sites incorrectly opens English Stack Overflow tour page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, russian-stackoverflow, tour, international-sites

For example, on ruSO.

> [image]

Pressing on link opens: https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

But should be: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour.

I've found string `bcad6de6449f923d84b7d6ed4bffe4b8`:

> Welcome to $siteName$! Take the 2-minute site tour to earn your first badge.

But looks like it gives a possibility to change only text, and not url.

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9668/15479

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like it's a notification generated *by* English Stack Overflow, otherwise it'd say "Добро пожаловать на сайт Stack Overflow на русском".

Viewing the message on SOru is what drives the translation, but the notification itself points to the site that triggered it.

Comment: Hm, interesting. So, you can receive this notifications only on SO? Because I didn't receive such notification on other SE sites.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica No, it is created when a user creates their first profile on any Q&A site, but it'll always link back to whatever site the user signed up on (SO, English, Gaming, etc. etc.).

Comment: Yeh, just created new acc on ruSO and this notification is correct. Thanks (: You can add your comment to the answer, and I will accept it.